# Binding Dropdownlist Values using Dictionery

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

My Datatable is like this

```
------------- ------------------ ---
 ID              VAL
------------- ------------------ ---
1                 Abc
2                 Pqr
```

I am adding it to `Dictionary<string, string>`(dt)  using `dt.Add(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString())` using a loop.

Now I need to bind the data to a dropdownlist
I done using

```
ddlAccHD.DataSource = achID;
ddlAccHD.DataBind();
```

Output is coming

`<option value="[36,asdf]">[36,asdf]</option>`

Both value and text is coming. Here `36` is `Value` and 'asdf' is `Key`

Comment: @yvind :I expected this one [<option value="36">asdf</option>], but result is [<option value="[36,asdf]">[36,asdf]</option>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the DataTextField and DataValueField properties.

```
ddlAccHD.DataSource = achID;
ddlAccHD.DataValueField = "Key";
ddlAccHD.DataTextField = "Value";
ddlAccHD.DataBind();
```